# Allowed characters in localization string

Tags: ios, regex, swift, localization

I am currently working on Swift script that allows type-checks by compiler for localization strings, something that was sorely needed for a long time. If you are interested, you can check the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/JiriTrecak/Laurine) to get better understanding.

**The problem**

Part of it is creation of methods from strings, when parser encounters special characters, that are meant to be changed in runtime (`%d`, `%f`, `%@` etc.). String like this:

```
"PROFILE_INFO" = "I am %@, I am %d years old and %.2fm in height!"
```

Will get converted to method with following signature:

```
func profileInfo(value1 : String, value2 : Int, value3 : Float { ...
```

What I am really curious about and what I could not find anywhere, not even in documentation, is what types are allowed in localization strings. I suspect it goes through default format and there is a lot of types to cover, in which case, I am curious what people used and what types can be omitted. I am using following regexp matching to find the special characters currently, and then converting them to appropriate data types:

```
let regexp = "%([0-9]*.[0-9]*(d|f|ld)|@|d)"
let matches = self.matchesForRegexInText("%([0-9]*.[0-9]*(d|f|ld)|@|d)", text: string)
```

I know this covers most of the usual cases, but obviously, I would like to have full coverage if possible.

**TLDR:**

Q1: What format specifiers are allowed in localization strings - are there any changes from classic string format or everything is the same?

Q2: Is there any better way to convert those characters to appropriate data type than using regexp to parse them out?

Thanks!

Comment: A localization string can contain any string, whether it's a valid format specifier or not.  And don't forget positional specifiers, which are often used.

Comment: ... and the string format specifiers are all documented in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html (but – as Avi said – that is completely unrelated to the allowed syntax in a Localizable.strings file).

Comment: I am only looking for answer for valid format specifiers - those are that the parser is looking for. As for positional specifiers, that does not apply to my project, as you always use main translation that does not contain them (that has to contain actual format specifiers).

Comment: Your Q1 is still unclear to me, even after your edit. The Localizable.strings file knows nothing about format specifiers, it is just a collection of key/value pairs. The result of the NSLocalizedString() is a new string which is passed to `String(format: ...)` and that is where the format specifiers are interpreted (as documented in the link in my last comment).

Comment: Btw (unrelated to your question), how do you handle the case where different languages use different string format specifiers (e.g. `"FOO" = "%d";` in the english strings file and `"FOO" = "%f";` in the czech strings file) ?

Comment: I understand. Please follow the link to project that you know that I really know what I am talking about :) what I am interested is String(format: ->...<-) this part. My parser takes this string and converts it to method that you can use in the code instead. In order to do that, I need two things - their position, and their data type :) and that is all I need to cover - I was simply asking, if that string in format parameter can contain the same characters as normal string (because NSLocalizedString(...) does not implicitly say that.

Comment: @MartinR I am not yet - as it is quite rare to see that situation. But even then, it will work properly from double -> int, the only problem would be int -> double. I will think about how to do it. Thanks!